# How to create multiple sdcards for android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, sd-card, android-sdcard

I need to test my app on a device with multiple sd cards. I couldn't find how to create secondary sd card on android emulators.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Use File SD Card

[image]

Check this link:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/mksdcard.html